# avalonia build on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, avalonia

I am making build for macOS, using avalonia. I tried making .app file but the macOS throws error [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zMIp.png). I tried empty project and make build, it worked. The only difference is in original project I am using .dll files for external calls.

FYI, when is click publish build and the unix file generated, double click that and console run and app started fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Avalonia has a guide for macos publishing: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/distribution-publishing/macos

Comment: yes I am following documentation. Specially this part. https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/distribution-publishing/macos#dotnet-bundle. Works fine with empty project but when I use in original project then, it won't.

Comment: Are those external libraries compatible with macos? They should have a `dylib` extension, it's the `dll` equivalent for osx.